# Victory Chart not drawing strokes in the negative axis for a valid data set in React

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

I am creating a horizontal bar chart using Victory that may get negative value and for that scenario i need the chart to draw on the -ve x axis .

some thing like below ---

[image]

But currently i am using version 33.0.5 and when I try with that version i see none of the bar charts draw in horizontal -ve x axis . Only when i degrade the version lower than 32.0.0 i get the charts draw on the -ve axis. Is there no way to achieve this in version 33.0.5 ? or any higher version . If yes what am i missing..

I tried doing in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-bar-chart-demo-forked-4ilv4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), currently the dependency for victory is set at 32.0.0 in which we will see the -ve x axis is not draw try lowering it below that and you will see the math has -ve x axis value too .

How to get this behaviour in higher versions of victory chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forked your sandbox and tried to fix it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-bar-chart-demo-forked-jf5gm

referred [https://spectrum.chat/victory/general/stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values-moving-horizontal-axis-labels-and-some-other-issues~6aec7554-208e-42fa-a310-ce6f780ef10d](https://spectrum.chat/victory/general/stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values-moving-horizontal-axis-labels-and-some-other-issues%7E6aec7554-208e-42fa-a310-ce6f780ef10d).